# Saddle-point problem vs saddle point problem

Tags: grammaticality, mathematics, compound-adjectives

I work in computer science/applied math, and I frequently see sentences such as "We wish to solve a bilinear saddle point problem." My problem is that this does not seem correct based on my understanding of compound adjectives. I personally prefer "bilinear saddle-point problem" because I see bilinear as a modifier of "saddle-point problem" whereas I see saddle-point as a compound adjective for "problem."

Comment: Saddle point is a compound noun, but how do you compute a problem?

Comment: ah sorry, edited to say "solve a" rather than "compute a," I was being too hasty. Would you then say that "saddle point problem" is also a compound noun then?

Comment: To clarify my follow-up: I don't see how "saddle point" being a compound noun solves my problem. I am specifically wondering about the case where we have a sentence such as "saddle point problem," or some similar third term such as "saddle point method."

Comment: My worry is along those lines: I prefer grouping saddle-point together in "bilinear saddle-point problem," because I think it should be parsed that way. Unfortunately it seems that there is no real established practice. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go stacking up attributive nouns for a long time, but nobody is apt to appreciate your greenhorn cowboy saddle point problem solution if you don't give them a bit of help parsing and grouping all that. :) The whole thing is still a Noun Phrase, and you should take care not to tire your reader.

Hyphenation is a matter of style preference, just like comma placement. It's up to you, the careful writer, to follow established practices in your field of publication.

Or not, as you choose.